# Getting error while opening web site in iframes using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I am having hard time to make my Iframe display my html string which happens to be

```
<div class="center wow fadeInDown">
   <iframe src="http://www.asana.com" style="width: 90%; height: 600px;" 
     name="internal"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you missed part of your question

Comment: Some web site doesn't allow you to run them inside an iframe, and this is one of them. Change site to for example _http://www.apple.com_ and above code works

Comment: Thanks for the reply LGSon                                                                            But i want to know whether we have any other code to display other website in our webpage using html